# How to handle unique symbol with typescript build

Tags: typescript

We have a function with below type definition

```
export declare function someFunction(args: SomeObject): {
    readonly [uniqueSymbol]: SomeData;
};
```

Corresponding Typescript code

```
const uniqueSymbol = Symbol('UNSAFE_INTERNAL_key');

const internalFunc = (args) => {
    return {
        [uniqueSymbol]: SomeData
    }
}

export function someFunction(args: SomeObject): {
    readonly internalFunc(args)
};
```

Now on any file where export a derived variable as below, we get error
error TS4023: Exported variable 'someVariable' has or is using name 'uniqueSymbol' from external module "path/to/file" but cannot be named.

```
export const someVariable = someFunction(someArg);
```

Meta Info

- Typescript v5.4.2
- Setup - Typescript with Project References
- TSconfig

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./out-tsc/reference-base",
            "incremental": true,
            "composite": true,
            "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": false,
            "disableSolutionSearching": false,
            "disableReferencedProjectLoad": false,
            "target": "es2020",
            "lib": [
                "es2022",
                "dom"
            ],
            "jsx": "react",
            "module": "esnext",
            "moduleResolution": "node10",
            "resolveJsonModule": true,
            "noEmit": false,
            "importHelpers": true,
            "isolatedModules": false,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
            "esModuleInterop": true,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
            "strict": true,
            "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": false,
            "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
            "declaration": true,
            "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
            "preserveConstEnums": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "noImplicitThis": true,
            "strictNullChecks": true,
            "strictFunctionTypes": true,
            "strictBindCallApply": true,
            "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
            "alwaysStrict": true,
            "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true
        },
        "files": [
            "./typings/store.d.ts",
            "./typings/svg.d.ts",
            "./typings/txt.d.ts",
            "./typings/uxm.d.ts",
        ]
    }
```

I tried running `tsc -b /path/to/tsconfig.json`

Expectation should have build the types

Comment: How did you define `uniqueSymbol`? Do you have `declare const uniqueSymbol: unique symbol;` somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now your code at the top has undeclared types and values that makes it impossible to proceed without wild speculation.

Comment: @qrsngky - Updated Description with corresponding typescript code

Comment: Note that the update still isn't a [mre] because you're using undeclared things like `SomeObject`. Could you [edit] it so that when we paste it into our own IDEs we see what you're seeing without introducing other issues? You might say "oh well it's obvious `SomeObject` is whatever you want it to be" but sometimes the choice will make a difference, so it's best to just start from a common [mre] we all can interact with. Thanks!

Comment: I think `declare const uniqueSymbol: unique symbol;` should added to the definitions file. It does not need to be `export`ed, but it makes a difference.